# D3 multi series line graph missing 3rd line

Tags: d3.js, graph, line

I apologize if this seems like a repeat.  I've seen a lot of similar threads, but none seems to be solving the exact problem I have.

I need to create a multi-series line chart for a class.  I'm not well versed in javascript and am completely new to D3, so I'm working through this as best I can.  I started with this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

I copied the code in to an editor and all I've really done to it is change the format of the time scale to four digit year (which seems to be working), rename the variables "city" and "cities" to "category" and "categories", and relabel the Temperature axis with "Percent".

Here's my code:

```
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Change date format to four digit year.
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;
//x and y axes
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
//change from "basis" to "linear"
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    //changed d.temperature to d.percent
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.percent); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });
//changied variable "cities" to "categories"
  var categories = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
      //changed below to percent
        return {date: d.date, percent: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
//changed "cities" to "categories"
  y.domain([
  //Temp to percent
    d3.min(categories, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.percent; }); }),
    d3.max(categories, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.percent; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      //Changed Temperature to percent for label
      .text("Percent (%)");
    //Changed "city" to "category" and "cities" to "categories"
  var category = svg.selectAll(".category")
      .data(categories)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "category");

  category.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  category.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.percent) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
});

</script>
```

I know this is a lot - pretty much everything.  I just have no idea where the problem is.  If there is anyone willing to look at this, I'd appreciate it very much.  Here's a link to where my current graph is hosted:http://www.pitt.edu/~kac232/hmwrk1ptA_test.html

Currently, what's happening is that I am missing a line for one category, and also my paths are perfectly straight, whigh makes no sense to me.  I would expect them to stagger at least a little.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to kick yourself, but the error is in your data's headings.  You repeated the heading `Bachelor's degree or more`.  Change one of the names and it will work as expected.

Comment: The lumpiness of the line changes with this part:  .interpolate("basis").  Check here, toward the bottom, to see how they look different and are calculated: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js Also, a little food for design thought, if I'm working with percents, I like to hardcode y.domain as this: ([0, 100]). Because with percents, your actual, real max and min are 0 and 100, not necessarily the range of your data. You can show your data in its real, 0 to 100, context.

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate the answer.